# Why does my script return: HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: php, apache, http-error

There is a folder on my apache server containing several php scripts. All the php scripts in this folder work except for 1. All the php scripts including the script that doesn't work have the same rights.

When I run the script in my browser I get this error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Details that may be helpful:

PHP Version 7.0.11
Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)

Comment: what's in the (error) logs?

Comment: ___Details that may be helpful:___  the code from the script that blows your server up!!! PHP Code can be written so badly that it can cause 500 errors

Comment: Its not just about rights, even a syntax error can generate that error on a lot of setups

Comment: PHP7.0.11 with Apache 2.2.15 Its amazing what you can do with a unix OS

Comment: Have you successfully run the script before from a different folder or server?

Comment: you have an "answer" below; it's out of our hands now. If you took off somewhere, then so have we and you'll need to either take it up with the answer given or ping one of us. I asked if anything appeared in logs but no response. Good luck with this, really.

Comment: should we close this topic?  it has very few answers and OP is not responding...

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, I was distracted from my computer. @Fred-ii- there is nothing in the error logs.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The script is very large, so it could definately be an problem with the code, thanks for pointing this out as I didn't know problems in the code could cause such errors..

Comment: @BastiaanWW can you add error reporting to "all" your files http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php to see if that doesn't pick up on anything? Might be something related to `.htaccess`, and/or something in your server setup. Is this on local or hosted? If you're using classes/functions, sometimes you need to omit `?>`; it could be anything really.

Comment: @RiggsFolly What do you mean with your comment about php7.0.11 and Apache 2.2.15, is that not a good combination on a linux OS? It is a freshly installed server and all the scripts are working on the old system (with lower php version and apache).

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just added all the error reporting with the function from your link. However, it doesn't throw any error. It still says "the page on .... doesn't work". It is hosted on my own VPS

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried removing ?> at the end and also added exit; right at the start of the script, but both didn't work. However, if I delete all the code and then echo 'HELLO'; the script works. It is just a matter of building the code up piece by piece to track down the exact problem.

Comment: @BastiaanWW That's what I was going to suggest earlier, that you place breaks here and there to see where it starts to break by removing them one at a time. It's a lenghty process, but it gets the job done.

Comment: If its a fresh install, why did you not go with Apache 2.4, its the latest greatest afterall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Apache status code of 500 means "internal server error".  Without seeing the code that is producing this error it is hard to say what is causing it but the first things to check are server configuration and your .htaccess file.  Make sure your server is running properly then check your .htaccess file as a bad rule can force some types of PHP to malfunction.  As @RiggsFolly stated, it is also possible that the problem is some very poorly written PHP which can be tested by replacing it with a simple program like:

`<?php
    echo "test";
?>`

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION: In my case the problem of 500 error was the upgrade from php 5.x to 7; BUT: I imagine this error can come from many other reasons, so if it does not apply, good luck finding the other solutions. In this case, it worked - and the solution is to rewrite the code or downgrade to old PHP version until you re-code the incompatible parts.

EXPLANATION / DEBUGGING PROCESS: After several tests to identify what is happening (commenting parts of code, testing functions, reading documentation), I found that deprecated functions from previous versions of PHP will generate a 500 Error.

For example, in a script written for PHP<7 you may still have old mysql queryes like mysql_connect, and once your server is updated to 7 (and you must use mysqli), this script will throw 500 error.
I imagine this happens to any other function that became deprecated.

In your case, my bet is most of the scripts are compatible with 7, one is not.